# Defining own style in preamble to center all tables

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to generate documents in pdf format using latexpdf target. I would like to slightly customize my document output, namely forcing positioning of figures and centering of tables. 
I managed to force positioning of my figures, however I can't figure out how to center my tables.

This is how I forced figures to be centered (excerpt from conf.py):

```
latex_elements = {
'preamble': '
    \\usepackage{float}
    \\let\\origfigure=\\figure
    \\renewenvironment{figure}[6]     
    {\\origfigure[H]}{\\endlist}'
```

What should I include in the preamble to center all tables?